# POST to vsts release api endpoint in C#

Tags: c#, .net, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I want to make a POST request to vsts create release api, sample:
POST `https://fabrikam.vsrm.visualstudio.com/MyFirstProject/_apis/release/releases?api-version=4.1-preview.6`

with the below request body:

```
{
  "definitionId": 1,
  "description": "Creating Sample release",
  "artifacts": [
    {
      "alias": "Fabrikam.CI",
      "instanceReference": {
        "id": "2",
        "name": null
      }
    }
  ],
  "isDraft": false,
  "reason": "none",
  "manualEnvironments": null
}
```

Can anyone please give me some pointers to do the same coding in C#. I am lost at the moment.

Kind Regards.

Edit1:
I have the below code to fetch the response, i want to make a POST to it:

```
class Program    
{    
    public async void GetProjects()
    {
        try
        {
            var personalaccesstoken = "PAT";

            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                    new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",
                    Convert.ToBase64String(
                        System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
                            string.Format("{0}:{1}", "", personalaccesstoken))));

                using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(
                            "https://sample.vsrm.visualstudio.com/MyFirstProject/_apis/release/releases?api-version=4.1-preview.6").Result)


                    //POST to response with Json body

                {
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                    string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Program prog = new Program();
        prog.GetProjects();    
    }                
}
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not where you come for pointers. Make an attempt to solve your problem. Research how to make a POST request to an API. Try it. If you get stuck with your implementation, show your work and explain how it's not working. Provide a [MCVE].

Comment: Do not post code in comments. It needs to be part of your question where it can be properly formatted.

Comment: Thanks mason researching just that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, i was able to do this with the help of RestSharp:

```
 var client = new RestClient("https://demouser.vsrm.visualstudio.com/MyFirstProject/_apis/release/releases?api-version=4.1-preview.6");
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic TWFuaXNoX0JpbHVuZ0BhZC5pbmZvc3lzLmNvbTpqbXZzNzQzeTZzcjR2cWFjY3Y0ZnpmbXk1ZTNra2tiYm03aDJjb29wMmZ5bjZ2MjZ1NW9x");
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            request.AddParameter("undefined", "{\r\n  \"definitionId\": 1,\r\n  \"description\": \"Creating Sample release\",\r\n  \"artifacts\": [\r\n    {\r\n      \"alias\": \"_MyFirstProject\",\r\n      \"instanceReference\": {\r\n        \"id\": \"2\",\r\n        \"name\": null\r\n      }\r\n    }\r\n  ],\r\n  \"isDraft\": false,\r\n  \"reason\": \"none\",\r\n  \"manualEnvironments\": \"PROD\"\r\n}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Comment: i will be updating this thread with the same POST request using HttpClient

Comment: You can mark your own answer by clicking √ symbol in the left of the answer.